# resilience4j - Spring Boot Application run failure

Tags: spring-boot, maven, resilience4j

**pom.xml
=============**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.telstra.resilience</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Resilience4j</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId> 
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.197</version> 
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
    
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Main Class
==================**

```
package com.telstra.resilience.demo;

import java.net.URI;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.route;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse.permanentRedirect;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> redirectRoot() {
        return route(GET("/"),
                req -> permanentRedirect(URI.create("/actuator")).build());
    }

}
```

**I have three Service classes and three Controllers. The build is successful but the Application run is failing as below errors:**

2020-10-18 21:13:15.926  INFO 47072 --- [           main] c.t.resilience.demo.DemoApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-18 21:13:16.481  WARN 47072 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'stream-circuitbreaker-events' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-10-18 21:13:16.482  WARN 47072 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix-stream-circuitbreaker-events' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-10-18 21:13:16.675  INFO 47072 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-10-18 21:13:16.696  INFO 47072 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-10-18 21:13:16.901  INFO 47072 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=1e499821-9d88-3e1e-b828-98e81518634b
2020-10-18 21:13:17.414  INFO 47072 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-18 21:13:17.437  INFO 47072 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-18 21:13:17.520  INFO 47072 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-10-18 21:13:17.660  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-10-18 21:13:17.720  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2020-10-18 21:13:17.905  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-10-18 21:13:18.071  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-10-18 21:13:18.367  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-10-18 21:13:18.378  INFO 47072 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-18 21:13:20.160  INFO 47072 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-10-18 21:13:20.569  WARN 47072 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration$MicrometerReactiveResilience4JCustomizerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: entryMap
2020-10-18 21:13:20.580  INFO 47072 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-18 21:13:20.580  INFO 47072 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-10-18 21:13:20.582  INFO 47072 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-18 21:13:20.582  INFO 47072 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-18 21:13:20.584  INFO 47072 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-10-18 21:13:20.608  INFO 47072 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-18 21:13:20.618 ERROR 47072 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration$MicrometerReactiveResilience4JCustomizerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: entryMap
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.telstra.resilience.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: entryMap
at io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.internal.InMemoryCircuitBreakerRegistry.getAllCircuitBreakers(InMemoryCircuitBreakerRegistry.java:127) ~[resilience4j-circuitbreaker-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at io.github.resilience4j.micrometer.tagged.TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics.bindTo(TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics.java:65) ~[resilience4j-micrometer-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration$MicrometerReactiveResilience4JCustomizerConfiguration.init(ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted

**If anyone has seen a similar issue please help!**

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ?,if yes please update the answer,  i am facing the same , @Shalini Pandit

Answer (score 0):

exclude resilience4j from spring cloud dependency